# Inserting input values into sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

The program runs fine but it doesn't insert anything in the DB.  I don't get it!

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('C:\\SQLite\\test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

answer = "ok"

while answer != "":

    title = raw_input("Enter film: ")
    year = raw_input("Enter year: ")
    director = raw_input("Enter director: ")

    cursor.execute("insert into films (title, year, director) values (?, ?, ?)", (title, year, director))

    answer = raw_input("Continue?  ")

conn.close()
```

Comment: `commit` your changes before closing the connection.